# Why was an An-124, and not a C-5A Galaxy, used to transport theAtlas V?

Tags: ula

First stages of Atlas V rocket used to be transported by air on Antonov-124 cargo aircraft. Later Lockheed-Martin switched to transporting by water.

**Why C-5 Galaxy wasn't used instead of An-124?**

Although first stage of Atlas V has Russian-built RD-180 engine, the stages were assembled in USA, and could have ITAR-restricted components.

An-124 aircraft are operated by Volga-Dnepr company, with Russian-speaking crews from Ukraine, Russia, etc.

So it's some surprising.

Was C-5 airplane technically unable to transport first stages of Atlas V? Or at least less suitable?

Or C-5 could do it, but there were some non-techical reasons (economical, political, other)?

Comment: Isn't the vertical height of the C5's cargo bay a bit tight? It looks like the rocket would fit in, but with *veeeery little* room to spare for packaging and handling.

Comment: @PcMan - you can be right. But I can't find dimensions of C-5 cargo cabin. I've found dimensions for An-124: 36.5*6.4*4.4 meters cargo cabin. Atlas V first stage has length 32.5 meters and diameter 3.8 meters.

Comment: Update: I've found heighf and width of cargo cabin of C-5: 5.76*4.10  meters. Some tighter than An-124, but is it the crucial factor? The rocket still fits, but it can require support structures  that don't fit. Here: https://man.fas.org/dod-101/sys/ac/c-5.htm

Comment: I *suspect* the answer may be along the lines of "you have to ask the USAF very nicely to borrow a C-5, whereas you can get an An-124 by paying an invoice to a commercial operator", but hard to prove that...

Comment: @Andrew - I'm not sure about this. For purely commercial launches - maybe, but for government (DoD, NASA) C-5 and C-17 are used regularly to transport satellires, for example. And many Atlas launches were for the government, but still first stages have been transported by An-124.

Comment: The question as modified is *much* easier to answer... Because the C5A *does not exist* any more, they have been modified to C5M